# Theos: cannot Override AppDelegate Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos, overriding

I want to make a Tweak for an App with Theos. The Method I want to change is in the AppDelegate.

I try to set the argument of the setupBG Method to YES every time that the app is opened. However, the app loads as if nothing happened and the Argument remains unchanged...

The Filter is set to the Bundle identifier of the app.

Here is the Tweak code: *(I have tried many possible solutions but none worked...)*

```
@interface AppDelegate: UIResponder

-(void) setupBG: (BOOL)bg;

@end

%hook AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        %orig;
        [self setupBG:YES];
        return YES;
}
%end
```

The Tweak compiles without errors and it is installed to the device successfully.
**Any idea why the argument isn't overridden?**

Comment: If you check the device console, do you see your tweak being injected? Is the filter file for your tweak setup properly?

Comment: No... So maybe it's not the correct class that I hook? But I also tried top do something similar with flex but also didn't work....